# How to combine two history commits without making the whole history linear?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, rebase, git-commit

For example I have a commit history like this

```
*   commit XXX
|\  Merge: XXX XXX
| |
| |     Merge branch 'dev'
| |
| * commit XXX
| |
| |     e
| |
| * commit XXX
| |
| |     d
| |
| * commit XXX
| |
| |     c
| |
* | commit XXX
| |
| |     b
| |
* | commit XXX
|/  
|   
|       a
|
* commit XXX

      init
```

Note that commit a, b and c, d, e are on different branches, and they have already merged.
How do I combine commit c and d without changing everything else?
I want the final history to be like this

```
*   commit XXX
|\  Merge: XXX XXX
| |
| |     Merge branch 'dev'
| |
| * commit XXX
| |
| |     e
| |
| * commit XXX
| |
| |     c + d
| |
* | commit XXX
| |
| |     b
| |
* | commit XXX
|/  
|   
|       a
|
* commit XXX

      init
```

I tried `git rebase -i`  onto the commit `init` and change the commit `d` to `fixup` but it makes everything linear.

Comment: Try `git rebase -i -r` to preserve the merge commits.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it is already very close to what I want. But I find that it complains conflict at positions where merge happens, even if I have already resolved the merge before. Is there any way it can just follow the previous merge?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r), you need to resolve them manually again.

Comment: Finally... I figured out everything. Basically everytime there's some conflict I just need to `git checkout <previous_merge_commit_id> .`